# Как в SVG сделать так, чтобы при использовании use работали градиенты из defs?

Tags: html5, svg, svg-animation, svg-спрайт

К примеру у меня есть подготовленный документ с SVG-спрайтами, в котором я объявляю каждую иконку через **`<symbol>`**. Но когда я использую эти иконки через **`<use>`** у меня не работают градиенты из **`<defs>`**, как я понял это из-за **#shadow-root**.

Как сделать чтобы они заработали?

Пример кода:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none">

  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="paint3_linear" x1="109.5" y1="-16" x2="109.5" y2="46" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop stop-color="#7A7A7A"></stop>
      <stop offset="1"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

      <symbol id="icon_opening-text-1"><svg width="221" height="39" viewBox="0 0 221 39" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M9.97656 12.6426H15.1758C19.9453 12.6426 23.4831 13.4876 25.7891 15.1777C28.0951 16.8535 29.248 19.4674 29.248 23.0195C29.248 25.9271 28.1882 28.1543 26.0684 29.7012C23.9629 31.2337 20.9336 32 16.9805 32H0.265625V0.503906H26.7773V6.88477H9.97656V12.6426ZM9.97656 25.2324H14.9609C18.0117 25.2324 19.5371 24.1296 19.5371 21.9238C19.5371 19.9902 18.0117 19.0234 14.9609 19.0234H9.97656V25.2324Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"></path>
    <path d="M47.6258 0.503906H63.8035C67.327 0.503906 69.9624 1.3418 71.7098 3.01758C73.4715 4.69336 74.3523 7.07812 74.3523 10.1719C74.3523 13.3516 73.3927 15.8366 71.4734 17.627C69.5685 19.4173 66.6538 20.3125 62.7293 20.3125H57.4012V32H47.6258V0.503906ZM57.4012 13.9316H59.7859C61.6622 13.9316 62.9799 13.6094 63.7391 12.9648C64.4982 12.306 64.8777 11.4681 64.8777 10.4512C64.8777 9.46289 64.5483 8.625 63.8895 7.9375C63.2306 7.25 61.9917 6.90625 60.1727 6.90625H57.4012V13.9316Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"></path>
    <path d="M92.6441 0.503906H118.726V7.22852H102.398V12.2344H117.545V18.6582H102.398V24.8672H119.199V32H92.6441V0.503906Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"></path>
    <path d="M137.705 0.503906H147.438V11.5254H158.073V0.503906H167.848V32H158.073V19.2598H147.438V32H137.705V0.503906Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"></path>
    <path d="M220.558 38.8535H212.716V32H192.607V38.8535H184.786V24.7383H188.03C189.849 19.6536 190.759 13.9173 190.759 7.5293V0.503906H217.163V24.7383H220.558V38.8535ZM207.431 24.7383V8.23828H199.611V8.64648C199.611 13.0007 198.873 18.3646 197.398 24.7383H207.431Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"></path>
    </svg>

    </symbol>
</svg>


<div class="icon">
    <svg>
      <use xlink:href="#icon_opening-text-1"></use>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT ок)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первая неточность - не указан второй цвет в градиенте, допустим я выбрал `stop-color="gold"`, вы можете выбрать любой другой цвет

```
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="paint3_linear" x1="109.5" y1="-16" x2="109.5" y2="46" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="5%"  stop-color="#7A7A7A" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="gold"/> 
    </linearGradient>  
  </defs>
```

Лучше не указывать `style="display:none"`, так как применение `<symbol>` и так скрывает содержание SVG до вызова его командой `<use>`

Остальное смотрите в моем коде

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="221" height="39" viewBox="0 0 221 39" >

  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="paint3_linear" x1="109.5" y1="-16" x2="109.5" y2="46" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="5%"  stop-color="#7A7A7A" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="gold"/> 
 </linearGradient>  
  </defs>

      <symbol id="icon_opening-text-1"> 
    <path d="M9.97656 12.6426H15.1758C19.9453 12.6426 23.4831 13.4876 25.7891 15.1777C28.0951 16.8535 29.248 19.4674 29.248 23.0195C29.248 25.9271 28.1882 28.1543 26.0684 29.7012C23.9629 31.2337 20.9336 32 16.9805 32H0.265625V0.503906H26.7773V6.88477H9.97656V12.6426ZM9.97656 25.2324H14.9609C18.0117 25.2324 19.5371 24.1296 19.5371 21.9238C19.5371 19.9902 18.0117 19.0234 14.9609 19.0234H9.97656V25.2324Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"></path>
    <path d="M47.6258 0.503906H63.8035C67.327 0.503906 69.9624 1.3418 71.7098 3.01758C73.4715 4.69336 74.3523 7.07812 74.3523 10.1719C74.3523 13.3516 73.3927 15.8366 71.4734 17.627C69.5685 19.4173 66.6538 20.3125 62.7293 20.3125H57.4012V32H47.6258V0.503906ZM57.4012 13.9316H59.7859C61.6622 13.9316 62.9799 13.6094 63.7391 12.9648C64.4982 12.306 64.8777 11.4681 64.8777 10.4512C64.8777 9.46289 64.5483 8.625 63.8895 7.9375C63.2306 7.25 61.9917 6.90625 60.1727 6.90625H57.4012V13.9316Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"></path>
    <path d="M92.6441 0.503906H118.726V7.22852H102.398V12.2344H117.545V18.6582H102.398V24.8672H119.199V32H92.6441V0.503906Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"></path>
    <path d="M137.705 0.503906H147.438V11.5254H158.073V0.503906H167.848V32H158.073V19.2598H147.438V32H137.705V0.503906Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"></path>
    <path d="M220.558 38.8535H212.716V32H192.607V38.8535H184.786V24.7383H188.03C189.849 19.6536 190.759 13.9173 190.759 7.5293V0.503906H217.163V24.7383H220.558V38.8535ZM207.431 24.7383V8.23828H199.611V8.64648C199.611 13.0007 198.873 18.3646 197.398 24.7383H207.431Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"></path>
    

    </symbol> 
 </svg>

 <div class="icon">
    <svg>
      <use xlink:href="#icon_opening-text-1"></use>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Заработало, благодарю! Неужели это было из-за display:none) второй цвет не указан из-за фигмы, при экспорте, если стоит полностью черный цвет, он не добавляет его.

Comment: @Absens Ex Да не за что :) В градиенте обязательно нужно указывать два цвета, чтобы быть уверенным, что это работает везде, во всех браузерах. А примеры анимации, что-ли не понравились? Специально добавил для вас, чтобы вы увидели, какие штуки можно делать с градиентами

Comment: Не заметил, очень круто)

Answer (score 4):

### В качестве бонуса несколько примеров анимации градиента

В основном применяется анимация атрибута `offset`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="221" height="39" viewBox="0 0 221 39" >

  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="paint3_linear" x1="109.5" y1="-16" x2="109.5" y2="46" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="5%"  stop-color="#7A7A7A" >
     <animate dur="4s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="0;1;1;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </stop>
        <stop offset="95%" stop-color="yellowgreen">
           <animate dur="4s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="0;1;1;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </stop> 
 </linearGradient>  
  </defs>

      <symbol id="icon_opening-text-1"> 
    <path d="M9.97656 12.6426H15.1758C19.9453 12.6426 23.4831 13.4876 25.7891 15.1777C28.0951 16.8535 29.248 19.4674 29.248 23.0195C29.248 25.9271 28.1882 28.1543 26.0684 29.7012C23.9629 31.2337 20.9336 32 16.9805 32H0.265625V0.503906H26.7773V6.88477H9.97656V12.6426ZM9.97656 25.2324H14.9609C18.0117 25.2324 19.5371 24.1296 19.5371 21.9238C19.5371 19.9902 18.0117 19.0234 14.9609 19.0234H9.97656V25.2324Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"></path>
    <path d="M47.6258 0.503906H63.8035C67.327 0.503906 69.9624 1.3418 71.7098 3.01758C73.4715 4.69336 74.3523 7.07812 74.3523 10.1719C74.3523 13.3516 73.3927 15.8366 71.4734 17.627C69.5685 19.4173 66.6538 20.3125 62.7293 20.3125H57.4012V32H47.6258V0.503906ZM57.4012 13.9316H59.7859C61.6622 13.9316 62.9799 13.6094 63.7391 12.9648C64.4982 12.306 64.8777 11.4681 64.8777 10.4512C64.8777 9.46289 64.5483 8.625 63.8895 7.9375C63.2306 7.25 61.9917 6.90625 60.1727 6.90625H57.4012V13.9316Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"></path>
    <path d="M92.6441 0.503906H118.726V7.22852H102.398V12.2344H117.545V18.6582H102.398V24.8672H119.199V32H92.6441V0.503906Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"></path>
    <path d="M137.705 0.503906H147.438V11.5254H158.073V0.503906H167.848V32H158.073V19.2598H147.438V32H137.705V0.503906Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"></path>
    <path d="M220.558 38.8535H212.716V32H192.607V38.8535H184.786V24.7383H188.03C189.849 19.6536 190.759 13.9173 190.759 7.5293V0.503906H217.163V24.7383H220.558V38.8535ZM207.431 24.7383V8.23828H199.611V8.64648C199.611 13.0007 198.873 18.3646 197.398 24.7383H207.431Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"></path>
    

    </symbol> 
 </svg>

 <div class="icon">
    <svg>
      <use xlink:href="#icon_opening-text-1"></use>
    </svg>
</div>
```

**Пример заполнения круга с помощью градиента**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200" height="200">
      <linearGradient id="lg" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="royalblue"/>
          <stop offset="40%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="royalblue">
            <animate
              attributeName="offset"
              values="0;1;0"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
              dur="10s"
              begin="0s"/>
          </stop>
          <stop offset="40%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="royalblue">
            <animate
              attributeName="offset"
              values="0;1;0"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
              dur="10s"
              begin="0s"/>
          </stop>
          <stop offset="100%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="royalblue"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="url(#lg)" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>
```

**Вращение градиента**

```html
<svg width="100%"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

<defs id="DEF">
<linearGradient id="W" gradientTransform="rotate(0)">
 <stop stop-color="#aaa" offset="0"/>
 <stop stop-color="#533" offset=".25"/>
 <stop stop-color="#aaa" offset=".50"/>
 <stop stop-color="#533" offset=".75"/>
 <stop stop-color="#aaa" offset="1"/>
</linearGradient>
<clipPath id="CP">
 <rect x="45%" y="0" height="100%" width="10%"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
<rect y="0" height="100%" width="20%" fill="url(#W)" clip-path="url(#CP)">
<animate attributeName="x"  dur="2s" values="35%;45%" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</rect>
</svg>
```